# QFileInfo exists() and isFile() error

Tags: c++, qt, file, qfile

I'm trying to check if provided path exists and if it is a file.
So I wrote this piece of code:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>


bool Tool::checkPath(const QString &path){
    QFileInfo fileInfo(QFile(path));
    return (fileInfo.exists() && fileInfo.isFile());
}
```

I get following compiler errors:

`Error: request for member 'exists' in 'fileInfo', which is of non-class type 'QFileInfo(QFile)'`

`Error: request for member 'isFile' in 'fileInfo', which is of non-class type 'QFileInfo(QFile)'`

Why ? I'm reading through docs over and over again but I can't get it.
BTW Qt Creator is suggesting me these methods and completes them. But compiler don't like it.

Comment: Why do you need to construct a file? Simply use QFileInfo::QFileInfo(const QString & file) constructor instead.

Comment: I have just missed the constructor but I don't see the reason why it should do any harm. BUT it actually works when providing the path directly. Any idea why ? I'll appreciate an explanation.

Comment: I think compiler treats QFileInfo fileInfo(QFile(path)); as a function declaration and not as an object initialization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems [vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19691690/718925):
compiler thinks that

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(QFile(path));
```

is a function definition like `QFileInfo fileInfo(QFile path);`

Use instead something like:

```
QFile ff(file);
QFileInfo fileInfo(ff);
bool test = (fileInfo.exists() && fileInfo.isFile());
```

Comment: Or you could use the aggregate initialisation (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization): `QFileInfo fileInfo{QFile{path}}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(path)
bool test = fileInfo.exists() && fileInfo.isFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to my low reputation I cannot make comments, then here I put some lines about QFileInfo:

```
QFileInfo fileInfo("./.py");
bool test = fileInfo.exists() && fileInfo.isFile();
```

that example will fail!

I added in the check the baseName() value:

```
bool test = fileInfo.exists() && fileInfo.isFile() && !fileInfo.baseName().isEmpty();
```